# git rebase master with child branches

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have some child branches on master.

How I can rebase local/master on origin/master (after fetch) with all child branches, based on my local/master?

Other words, I have some:

```
*---*---*(master)---*---*---*(feature-A)
     \           \--*---*---*(feature-B)
      --*---*---*---*---*---*---*(origin/master)
```

I want get:

`*---*--*---*---*---*---*---*---*(origin/master)---*(master)---*---*---*(feature-A)
                                                            \--*---*---*(feature-B)`

If I do it in some steps, I must rebase each branch once with coping(?) a lot of commits.

Answer (score 2):

First of all take the latest `master` to your local repo

```
git pull --rebase
```

Then checkout to `feature-A` branch

```
git checkout feature-A
```

Then rebase `feature-A` branch

```
git rebase master
```

If you get any conflicts, fix them &,

```
git add .
git rebase --continue
```

untill you finishes your rebase.

Then you have to force push your feature-A branch to remote

```
git push origin feature-A --force
```

You have to repeat this to each & every branch

Comment: No way to rebase only master, and other A-B branches will follow rebase to master?

Comment: By doing the above steps to each & every feature branches, you will get the exact `I want get:` branch structure

Comment: I know how do it for some steps: `If I do it in some steps`
I want recursive rebase for all branches above local/master.
Your answer is in the documentation